# Using Python with Excel 2007

Tags: python, excel-2007

I want to write some python functions to extract lines from a number of text files, then parse the data and reformat it before writing to cells within an Excel 2007 dataTable.

I note that OpenPyXl specifically names Excel-2010 so I assume it cannot be used with Excel-2007. Is this assumption correct?

Is there anything else I should look at? (Freeware or Shareware or low licence fees are preferable.)

Comment: Take a look at  https://www.python-excel.org/   there are libraries like https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  or https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ designed to work with the older `xls` format instead of the newer `xlsx`